# Differentiate $\int_{0}^{x}\frac{dx}{x^2 + a^2} = \frac{1}{a} \tan^{-1}\frac{x}{a}$ under the integral sign?

Tags: integration, derivatives

Differentiate $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x}\frac{dx}{x^2 + a^2} = \frac{1}{a} \tan^{-1} \dfrac{x}{a}$ under the integral sign to find the value of $$\int_{0}^{x} \frac{dx}{(x^2 + a^2)^2}$$

---

I am getting something $\frac{1}{2a^3}tan^{-1}\frac{x}{a}$, but not sure of it .

Comment: $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x}\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^2 + a^2}$ makes no sense to begin with.

Comment: @DHMO, I think that's an (admittedly widespread) misconception.

Comment: @goblin At least it's confusing.

Comment: @DHMO, surely it's less confusing, because you can write things like $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \int_a \varepsilon dx = \varepsilon, \qquad \int_a \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \varepsilon dx = \varepsilon - \varepsilon(x:=a),$$ where $(x:=a)$ means evaluation at $x=a$, and $\int_a \varepsilon dx$ is shorthand for $\int_a^x \varepsilon dx$.

Comment: @DHMO, the formulae become even clearer if we void all that $dx$ nonsense: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \int_{x=a} \varepsilon = \varepsilon, \qquad \int_{x=a} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \varepsilon = \varepsilon - \varepsilon(x:=a).$$ This makes it really clear that integration and differentiation with respect to the same variable are almost inverses of each other, and the second formula makes explicit the precise way in which they aren't.

Comment: Look through my chat room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36727683#36727683

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x}\frac{\mathrm dt}{t^2 + a^2}
&=&
\displaystyle \frac{1}{a}\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{a}
\\
\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial(a^2)} \int_{0}^{x}\frac{\mathrm dt}{t^2 + a^2}
&=&
\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial(a^2)} \left(\frac{1}{a}\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{a}\right)
\\
\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x}-\frac{\mathrm dt}{(t^2 + a^2)^2}
&=&
\displaystyle \frac{\partial a}{\partial(a^2)} \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \left(\frac{1}{a}\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{a}\right)
\\
\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x}\frac{\mathrm dt}{(t^2 + a^2)^2}
&=&
\displaystyle -\frac{1}{2a} \left(\frac{-1}{a^2}\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{a} + \frac1a \frac{1}{1+\left(\frac xa\right)^2} \frac{-x}{a^2}\right)
\\
&=&\displaystyle \frac{1}{2a} \left(\frac{1}{a^2}\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{a} + \frac{x}{a(x^2+a^2)}\right)\\
&=&\displaystyle \frac{1}{2a^3} \left(\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{a}+\frac {ax}{x^2+a^2}\right)\\
\end{array}$$

---

Due to a suggestion on using $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial a}$ instead of $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial(a^2)}$,

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x}\frac{\mathrm dt}{t^2 + a^2}
&=&
\displaystyle \frac{1}{a}\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{a}
\\
\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \int_{0}^{x}\frac{\mathrm dt}{t^2 + a^2}
&=&
\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \left(\frac{1}{a}\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{a}\right)
\\
\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x}\frac{-2a\ \mathrm dt}{(t^2 + a^2)^2}
&=&
\displaystyle \frac{-1}{a^2}\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{a} + \frac1a \frac{1}{1+\left(\frac xa\right)^2} \frac{-x}{a^2}
\\
\displaystyle \int_{0}^{x}\frac{\mathrm dt}{(t^2 + a^2)^2}
&=&
\displaystyle -\frac{1}{2a} \left(\frac{-1}{a^2}\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{a} + \frac1a \frac{1}{1+\left(\frac xa\right)^2} \frac{-x}{a^2}\right)
\\
&=&\displaystyle \frac{1}{2a} \left(\frac{1}{a^2}\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{a} + \frac{x}{a(x^2+a^2)}\right)\\
&=&\displaystyle \frac{1}{2a^3} \left(\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{a}+\frac {ax}{x^2+a^2}\right)\\
\end{array}$$

Comment: I don't really recommend differentiating in terms of $a^2$. Obviously it works out, but it can be unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I thought differentiating with $a$ would be more complicated on the left. On the right, it's a simple chain rule, so I don't really see the complication.

Comment: That's fair. I just think it can be a bit troubling for younger students, but it's clearly correct and effectively the same thing.

Comment: I would not want to deal with $a$ on the left hand side. I don't even know how to do it. (EDIT: I know now.)

Comment: The only difference is that you pick up an extra factor of $2a$ on the LHS from chain rule which matches exactly with the $\frac{1}{2a}$ factor you have on the RHS in your approach. :)

Comment: @CameronWilliams satisfied?

Comment: I wouldn't say I was "shxt-talking" your approach (I even say it's completely correct and effectively equivalent), just saying it can be a little scary for some students. No need to get testy about it.

Comment: Hm, for some reason I couldn't fix one of the $\tan$'s... weird rendering problems

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt which $\tan$?

Comment: Nvm.... @DHMO :P